# Can I use 2FA on my github account when using EGit

Tags: github, egit

so I am trying to add my project to github but I keep getting a error saying I'm  not authorized and I was wanting to know if I need to take 2FA off to use EGit

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. In fact I found one issue on egit bug tracker about this feature. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426144

Answer (score 0):

You can use EGit with Github while leaving 2FA active. A way would be to use the SSH connection instead of the HTTPS connection. You need to define SSH certificates, but there would be no more need to enter your credentials in the IDE.